# Get protractor sessionId into a file

Tags: jasmine, protractor, saucelabs

I need to get the job ID / session ID from a protractor run into a file so I can create links to screenshots / videos at Saucelabs .  Is there a correct way to do this?

One approach I'm looking at is to get the session ID from the `browser` object then pass to a custom reporter that writes it to a file:

```
// protractor.conf.js
onPrepare: function () {

    var sessionIdP = q.defer();

    browser.getSession().then(function(session) {
        sessionIdP.resolve(session.getId());
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SessionIdWriter({
        sessionId: sessionIdP
    });
}
```

Should work but can this be done more cleanly?

I'm aware that Saucelabs offers a REST api that can return the latest job ID, but this presents a race condition with other users of the account.  Besides the ID is known locally so a call shouldn't be needed.

Comment: This is the way I do it.. I think this is why SL are using the sessionId, since it's available via selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for are `build: 'some build number'` and `name: 'my awesome webpage'` properties in the [capabilities](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L107) section of your config file. these parameters will be pass through to your SL account and show up in the test run table

more info available https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/#job-annotation

Comment: The SL sessionId is different from the build number & name; but as a side note, thanks for the `name: awesome webpage` tip, the "Untitled" on the SL results page was making my eyes bleed.